# Is it possible to map a @RestController only if it isn't already mapped?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

So I have a controller mapped to /App/Health and making some changes to the functionality, moving it into its own project to allow for just including it as a dependency rather than having to set it up manually.

However, a few services already have it set up and if possible, I'd like the new controller to only create itself only if the path isn't mapped by the old one..

Existing:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/App")
public class ApplicationController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/Health", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String health() {
        return "Ok!";
    }
}
```

New:

```
@RestController
public class HealthCheck {

    @RequestMapping("/App/Health")
    public String health() {
        return "Ok!";
    }
}
```

So, given both of these existing in two different packages, is it possible to make "New" optionally instantiate if the "Existing" doesn't?

Comment: Don't know if the registered request mappings are available for this, but you might look into [`@Conditional`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html). Or maybe [`@ConditionalOnMissingBean`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnMissingBean.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the above code just works.

Because the first defines RequestMethod.GET while the new one doesn't, which results in the new one mapping to all methods Except anything already bound specifically.

I added another endpoint that maps to everything BUT the RequestMethod.GET and returns an error, leading to the new one, which maps to "Everything available" either maps to the GET if the existing one doesn't, or to Nothing if the existing one does.

Answer (score 0):

If you distribute your code as a lib, using package-scan for it (and I guess that's the problem) is a weird. The app should control what beans it creates.

So you can setup beans manually via XML or Java config and if there is a controller that does the job, just don't create a bean for the one from the lib.